# Write formula in range from string

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I build a formula out of other formulas in my sheet with the `&-operator` and save it as a string. When I try to write it in a range with:

```
myTable.DataBodyRange(Index, 1).FormulaLocal = StringFormula
```

Run-time error '1004' appears. I tried it with `Formula` and `FormulaR1C1` but the same error appears. Trying this e.g.

```
myTable.DataBodyRange(Index, 1).FormulaLocal = "=2+3"
```

works fine.
Looking in `StringFormula` variable while stepping over it it contains the right formula in inverted commas: `"=(VLOOKUP..."`.
I tried to put `CHR(34)` around it but it just write the formula with inverted commas in the cell.

Comment: Can you paste more code? Certainly knowing what's in StringFormula will help us. Your code looks fine, there's a run-time error so we need more information to be able to replicate the error.

Comment: Clearly we can't help if you don't show us what the formula is that you're trying to put in the cell. There's an error in the formula; either find it yourself, or show us so we can help.

Comment: Found the mistake. I used `StringFormula = myTable.DataBodyRange(Index, 1).Formula` to put the formula in a string instead of `FormulaLocal`, so the `;` where changed to `,`. I conceived because of your tip. Thanks JLILI Amen!